# Property getBBox does not exist on type SVGElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg, types

I'm using d3, and I'd like to use the getBBox method that SVG elements have.

I'm using the following: `(d3Selection.node() as SVGElement).getBBox()`, however the TypeScript fails to compile due to the error in the title.

Is SVGElement the wrong type to use? I can it working using `any` instead, but this seems like a bit of an "unclean" solution.

Comment: I checked the hierarchy and the getBBox() method are not bound to `SVGElement`, but to `SVGGraphicsElement`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not all SVG elements have bounding boxes, `<defs>` for instance doesn't, neither does `<title>`, so yes SVGElement is the wrong type to use. You want [SVGGraphicsElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/idl.html)

Comment: SVGLocatable is removed in svg2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#Specifications

Comment: SVGGraphicsElement mostly replaces SVGLocatable. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `SVGElement`, `SVGSVGElement` is the correct type to use for accessing `<svg>` elements, where `getBBox()` method is available as well because of the inheritance from `SVGGraphicsElement`.

```
(d3Selection.node() as SVGSVGElement).getBBox()
```

Or if `d3Selection` is defined as

```
let d3Selection: D3.Selection<SVGSVGElement, {}, HTMLElement, any>
d3Selection.node().getBBox()
```

could be directly into usage.